# Prevent div containing image to resize when text added

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` centered in the site and containing a picture. The `div` extends its `height` to fit the picture as expected. Then I add some text and I expect it to lay out on the bottom of the `div`. But in addition to that the `div` also resizes a little bit so its `height` is `higher` than the `height` of the picture. Here is the exmaple:

Html:

```
<div class="siteContent">
    <img class="debug" src="../../Content/themes/base/images/pageTitle.png" /> 
    <span>
        aaa
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
.siteContent
{   
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: thin solid;
}
.debug
{
    border: thin solid;
}
```

The result:
[image]

The unwanted effect is marked red.

I was able to fix this for IE 8 and Firefox by modifiing the CSS like this:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
.siteContent
{   
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: thin solid;
    position: relative;
}
.siteContent span{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.debug
{
    border: thin solid;
}
```

After runnig this I got the right result in Mozilla:

[image]

However this does not work for Chrome and Safary. **How can make it work for all major browsers ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this happens because the image is aligned to the baseline of the text. try to set `vertical-align: bottom` or `vertical-align: text-bottom` for your image to solve this.

Comment: My pleasure. And if this solved your problem it would be nice to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I have a strange habit to not to accept answer imediatelly but just wait for a day or two... Most probably your answer will be accepted in few days.

Comment: No problem, i just thought you forgot that ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/WEF49/3/
Tested in IE, chrome and FF. This way img and span are bottom aligned and div do not have any extra space. Bad side is that div height is fixed to img height. If you do not mind fixed height on div this is cleanest solution.

html:

```
<div class="siteContent">
    <img class="debug" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzjvZihxljFMlEt_IOypeOWYCgPgEvVrZ_DnwVTws5uR_iC_oFIg" /> 
    <span>
        aaa
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.siteContent
{   
    width: 960px;
    height: 213px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: thin solid;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.debug
{
    border: thin solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding overflow:hidden to the div without height
+

```
<span style="clear:both">
        aaa
    </span>
+
<img src="..." style="clear:both" />
```

take the style="*" to your css file (ofcource )